# Issue when extending a matrix-like numpy array by adding extra list

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I wrote the following code that does: (1) Generate root matrix of shape `(3, 16)`, and (2) Generate 1000 binary vectors `C` such that each vector is added at the end of the root matrix iteratively one at a time.

The code is the following (python 2.7):

```
# STEP1: Generate root matrix 
root = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 16 - 1) for _ in range(16 - 1)]
root = [('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x) for x in root]
root = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in root], dtype=np.uint8)

# STEP2: Generate 1000 binary vectors
C = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 16 - 1) for _ in range(1000)]
C = list(set(C))
C = [('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x) for x in C]
C = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in C], dtype=np.uint8)

# Step3: For each vector of C, append it at the end of root matrix
for i in range(1000):
    batch = root[i:(i + (len(root)))]
    batch = np.append(batch, C[i])
    print(batch)
    # Continue to process batch after being extended by adding a new vector
```

The matrix `C` looks like this:

```
[[0 1 1 ..., 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 ..., 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 ..., 1 1 0]
 ..., 
 [1 1 0 ..., 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]]
```

The problem is that `np.append(batch, C[i])`merges all vectors into a single one but this is not what I want. My goal is to extend the `root` matrix from `(3, 16)` to be `(4,16)` by just adding a vector `C[i]` iteratively. How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of using `append`, I recommend collecting the arrays you want to join in a `list`, and doing one `np.array` or `concatenate`.  `np.append` is poorly written and too often confused with list append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can swap this:

```
batch = root[i:(i + (len(root)))]
batch = np.append(batch, C[i])
```

For this:

```
batch = np.append(batch, [C[i]], axis=0)
```

`axis` allows you to append two matrices on a particular dimension. So we make `C[i]` into a matrix and append it in dimension 0.

I am not sure what the intention of this `batch = root[i:(i + (len(root)))]` is but it shortens `batch` to a matrix the size of root every time so it will not increase in size. It actually shrinks as you near the end of `root`.

Also C is not always 1000 vectors. Making them unique removes some.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very easy