# Numpy appending arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to to grow an array/matrix with each iteration within a for loop.
Following is my code

```
import numpy as np


sino = []; 
for n in range(0, 4):
    fileName = 'D:\zDeflectionBP\data\headData_zdef\COSWeighted_trunk_' + str(n) + '.bin'
    f = open(fileName, "rb")
    data = np.fromfile(f, np.float32)
    sino = np.append(sino, data)
f.close()

fileName = 'D:\zDeflectionBP\data\headData_zdef\Head_FFS_COSWeighted.bin'
f = open(fileName, "wb")
f.write(bytes(sino))
f.close()
```

Each iteration the `data` is loaded witThere four

However, in the end, I found the size (in terms of number of bytes) of sino is twice as it should be.

For example:
Each size of `data`: 3MB
then, since I have four `data`, the size of the sino should be: 3MB X 4 = 12MB. 
But I found the size of the size is 24MB.

What is happening here? I'd like for `sino` to be only 12MB, which only contains data from the four `data` variable. How should I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please, stick with list append!  Hardly anyone uses `np.append` correctly.  If you must use `np.concatenate`.  That way you are forced to pay close attention to the dimensions of the arrays that you join.

Comment: @hpaulj: I am sorry I don't quite understand. Should I use or not use 'np.append()', or should I use 'np.concatenate()' instead?

Comment: Other recent questions where `np.append` gives problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913179/numpy-append-3d-vectors-without-flattening, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900858/issue-when-extending-a-matrix-like-numpy-array-by-adding-extra-list, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847798/numpy-array-append-is-not-working

Comment: @hpaulj: you mean I should use np.concatenate() instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sino` isn't a numpy array initially but a Python list.

Numpy converts it to a 64 bit array the first time by default on a 64 bit installation, after that it stays that way, twice as large as you expected.

All the times you append data it's converted to 64 bit, since that's the format of the target.

Make `sino` a `np.float32` array right from the start to solve the problem.

Comment: I see. How do I decalre it to be a numpy float32 array?

Comment: Example: numpy.array([], dtype="float32"). And see remark of @hpaulj.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!